# Permission based авторизация в микросервисах asp.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, аутентификация, микросервисы

Есть: `Users, Groups,  Roles, Permissions, UserRoles, UserGroups, GroupRoles, RolePermissions, GroupPermission.`

Сами пермишены выглядят как-то так:

```
Document.Read
Document.Create
Document.Update
Document.Delete
```

В административной панели эти пермишены присваиваются группам/ролям

Необходимо сделать авторизацию по permissions. Сейчас идея такая: есть сервис аутентификации/авторизации который имеет метод `LogIn` который отдаёт `JWT Token` для использования другими микросервисами и клиентом

**Но как хранить сами пермишены?** Просто получается, если их хранить как `static string` на api авторизации, на других api когда мы делаем `CheckAccess("PermissionName")` мы теряем "типобезопасность" и можем накосячить. 
Если хранить пермишены на каждом отдельном микросервисе, то тогда такая проблема исчезает, но появляется проблема регистрации этих пермишенов в БД, и присвоение их ролям/группам.

Очень хотелось, конечно, в сервисе писать `CheckAccess(Permissions.Document.Read)`

Может есть способ вообще динамически навешивать на методы api различные permissions?

Может ли мои идеи в корне не верны?